# How to set inspection profile for the editor in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-inspection

I'm suddenly missing a lot of in-editor warnings and errors. When I manually run my inspections, the things I'm missing show up just fine, but how do I get them to show in the editor window again?

For example, if I put an incorrect `package` statement in my class, it will show up when I run Analyze -> Inspect Code..., but not the editor window won't complain or offer a quick fix.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your inspection highlighting level is set to `syntax` or higher?

Comment: @Matthew I'm not sure, where can I find that setting?

Comment: in the right lower corner of IntelliJ, there will be an icon of a man with hat, Click on it and you can set your syntax level.

Comment: In the far bottom right corner (right next to the padlock icon) there is an inspector icon,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can access all settings of intellij code inspection

[image: code inspection inttelij]

When you run "Analyze -> Inspect Code" the IDE will effectively not do any highlight. Be sure that in the code inspection, the highlight level is on "inspections" or at least on "syntax" as Matthew mentioned

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but this made me find the "Error Highlighting" option, which allowed me to set the IDE inspection profile back to what it should have been. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Also note that the icon you point to is disabled unless you have a Java file open

Comment: You are welcome !
About the fact that the icon is disabled, for me it's always enabled, depend-less of the opened file. Even if the extension is unknown. You may have an outdated version of intellij. 
The code inspection have a spelling correction feature that work on any file.

edit: or maybe it's because I have the ultimate version and not the community one

Comment: I'm on Ultimate 2019.1.2, but I have the spelling inspection disabled. That might be the difference